# Draw a quadratic spline through points in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

Based on this great question: [How to draw a smooth curve passing through some points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303251/how-to-draw-a-smooth-curve-passing-through-some-points)

How would one do this in lattice?

```
plot(rnorm(120), rnorm(120), col="darkblue", pch=16, xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(-4,4))
points(rnorm(120,-1,1), rnorm(120,2,1), col="darkred", pch=16)
points(c(-1,-1.5,-3), c(4,2,0), pch=3, cex=3)
xspline(c(-1,-1.5,-3), c(4,2,0), shape = -1)
```

[image: Should look like that:]

Here is similar data, formatted more appropriately for a `lattice` plot:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(120), rnorm(120,-1,1)),
                  y=c(rnorm(120), rnorm(120,2,1)),
                  l=factor(rep(c('B','R'),each=120))
)
spl <- data.frame(x=c(-1,-1.5,-3), 
                  y=c(4,2,0)
)
```

And here is what the linked question gave, translated to `lattice`:

```
xyplot(y ~ x,
       data=dat,
       groups=l,
       col=c("darkblue", "darkred"),
       pch=16,
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x=spl$x, y=spl$y, pch=3, cex=3)
         ## panel.spline(x=spl$x, y=spl$y)              ## Gives an error, need at least four 'x' values
         panel.superpose(x, y, ...,
                         panel.groups = function(x, y, ...) {
                           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
                         }
         )
       },
       xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(-4,4)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This question is producing some great answers. One of the tricky things in 'lattice' plotting is how one properly annotates existing plots. There are a variety of techniques that can be applied within the original function or to overly existing functions.

Comment: Whether or not you adopt the specific implementation in my answer below, the [`grid.xspline()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grid/html/grid.xspline.html) function will likely come in handy...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Indeed, `grid.xspline()` works for the plain `lattice` code as well.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I added a `ggplot2` solution using `grid.xspline()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a line-for line 'translation' of the **base** graphics solution into **lattice**.
(The directness of the translation is made possible by the 
`+` operator supplied by the **latticeExtra** package. See [`?layer`](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/man/layer.html) for details of its usage.)

The final line invokes [`grid.xspline()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grid/html/grid.xspline.html), an exact **grid** analogue of the **base** graphic function `xspline()`.

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)
library(latticeExtra)

xyplot(rnorm(120)~rnorm(120), pch=16, col="darkblue", 
       xlim = c(-3.1, 3.1), ylim = c(-4.1, 4.1)) +
xyplot(rnorm(120,2,1) ~ rnorm(120,-1,1), pch=16, col="darkred") +
xyplot(c(4,2,0) ~ c(-1,-1.5,-3), pch=3, cex=3) +
layer(grid.xspline(c(-1,-1.5,-3), c(4,2,0), shape = -1, default.units="native"))
```

(One peculiar detail of **grid** does pop up in the final line above: like several other of its low-level line-drawing functions, `grid.xspline()` defaults to `"npc"` units instead of the usually-desired `"native"` units used as defaults by `grid.points()` and many other `grid.*()` functions. Obviously that's easy enough to change --- once you're aware of it!)

[image]

Comment: `latticeExtra` is something that I haven't used.  I'll investigate it, although I prefer the "callback" nature of `lattice` as it is.

Comment: Love that grid-iffied answer!

Comment: +1 for this great answer! I am pretty sure that this can be generalized to any base graphic mathematical|statistical|graphical function.I mean every time you need something in base you find the homologous in grid.

Comment: @agstudy -- Not sure if that's **strictly** true, but yeah, I've found it to be so every time I've needed it. It helps a lot that [Paul Murrel](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/) (bless him) has been so deeply involved in implementing *both* the **base** and **grid** graphical systems!

Comment: @DWin Thanks! The only tricky part was having to reset the `default.units` of `grid.xspline()`, a **grid** oddity [that has bit folks before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376596/lines-using-the-r-grid-package/12379106#12379106). (I've now added a mention of that to my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a little bit tricky but works.

```
plot(rnorm(120), rnorm(120), col="darkblue", pch=16, xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(-4,4))
points(rnorm(120,-1,1), rnorm(120,2,1), col="darkred", pch=16)
points(c(-1,-1.5,-3), c(4,2,0), pch=3, cex=3)
```

I use `xspline` without producing the draw

```
dd <- xspline(c(-1,-1.5,-3), c(4,2,0), shape = -1,draw=FALSE)
```

Then I use the points produced witn `panel.lines`

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y ~ x,
       data=dat,
       groups=l,
       col=c("darkblue", "darkred"),
       pch=16,
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x=spl$x, y=spl$y, pch=3, cex=3)
         panel.lines(dd$x,dd$y)
         panel.superpose(x, y, ...,
                         panel.groups = function(x, y, ...) {
                           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
                         }
         )
       },
       xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(-4,4)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but I don't like that it requires the base plotting functions to work.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Thanks. But why ? I am curious. because it generates the base plots? Does a wrapper to xspline where I call basic plot (in "invisible" manner) is an acceptable solution for you ?

Comment: I'm looking to avoid base graphics functions.  If I don't get anything better than my own answer, I'll accept this simply because it does work.

Comment: I don't think agstudy's answer actually depends on the preceding `plot` or `points` calls. It succeeds by just starting with the assignment to `dd`.

Comment: @DWin Sorry for my poor english.  I didn't understand exactly your comment. have i to change something in my answer?

Comment: My comment was not criticizing your post at all. I was suggesting that it was not deficient in the features that Matthew was suggesting. It is in the base graphics package but it is not using base graphic features to return the mathematical results.

Comment: @DWin It produces slightly different results (length of vectors), depending on the state of the active graphics device.  For example, try the command after `plot(-1,-1)` then after `plot(100, 100)` and compare.  It also fails if there is no active graphics device.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution, by an attempt to use Josh solution with `grid.xspline` in `ggplot2`. I think it is interesting to get a parallel between ggplot2/lattice.

[image]

```
## prepare the data
dat <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(120), rnorm(120,-1,1)),
                 y=c(rnorm(120), rnorm(120,2,1)),
                 l=factor(rep(c('B','R'),each=120))
)
spl <- data.frame(x=c(-2,-1.5,-3), 
                  y=c(4,2,0)
)
## prepare the scatter plot
library(ggplot(2))
p <- ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=x,y=y,color=l))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data=spl,aes(x=x,y=y),color='darkred',size=5)
library(grid)
ff <- ggplot_build(p)
```

My idea is to use the scales generated by ggplot2, to create the spline in the same  panel than the scatterplot. Personally I find this tricky, and I hope that someone comes with a better solution.

```
xsp.grob <- xsplineGrob(spl$x, spl$y,
                        vp=viewport(xscale =ff$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.range,
                                    yscale = ff$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range),
                        shape = -1, default.units="native")
p
grid.add(gPath='panel.3-4-3-4',child=xsp.grob)
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to this, based on the answer to this question:  [Quadratic spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925533/quadratic-spline)

Using package `splines`

Replace `panel.splines(`...`)` (commented out above) with this code:

```
         local({
           model <- lm(y ~ bs(x, degree=2), data=spl)
           x0 <- seq(min(spl$x), max(spl$x), by=.1)
           panel.lines(x0, predict(model, data.frame(x=x0)))
         })
```

[image]

From Josh O'Brien's excellent suggestion, `grid.xspline()` can replace the commented-out `panel.splines(`...`)` line, resulting in the exact plot as in the base question, linked above (except for the margins):

```
         grid.xspline(spl$x, spl$y, shape = -1, default.units="native")
```

[image]

Comment: @agstudy it's not very readable, and besides, there's no percentage in accepting my own answer.

Comment: Wow. You got that answer from the answer or comments to the cited link. Y'er a better man than I.

Comment: @DWin Specifically, Josh's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of a spline panel from Deepayan Sarkar

```
panel.smooth.spline <-  function(x, y,
                                 w=NULL, df, spar = NULL, cv = FALSE,
                                 lwd=plot.line$lwd, lty=plot.line$lty,col, 
                                 col.line=plot.line$col,type, ... )
{
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  y <- as.numeric(y)
  ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
  if (sum(ok) < 1)
    return()
  if (!missing(col)) {
    if (missing(col.line))
      col.line <- col
  }
  plot.line <- trellis.par.get("plot.line")
  spline <-   smooth.spline(x[ok], y[ok],
                            w=w, df=df, spar = spar, cv = cv)
  pred = predict(spline,x= seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=150))
  panel.lines(x = pred$x, y = pred$y, col = col.line,
              lty = lty, lwd = lwd, ...)
  panel.abline(h=y[which.min(x)],col=col.line,lty=2)
}
```

Comment: This may solve the problem that I actually want to solve, but doesn't work for the example:  `Error using packet 1  need at least 4 unique 'x' values` -- as does `panel.spline`.